# How do you use namespacing with php packages and phpunit?

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit, package

*EDITED to add code for MainClass as requested in comments.*

I'm trying to learn how to make php packages and how to use phpunit at the same time, I may be using all the wrong terminology here and doing everything wrong..

Everything works as expected when I import the package with composer. I decided to add some unit tests as I finally started to see how they could be useful to me however I am having trouble and I suspect it has something to do with namespaces but I'm not sure.

I have put the tests in their own directory and used use statements at the top of the test classes for importing the main src classes. So, for example, in a test class I have the following:

```
use myname\Package\MainClass;
use myname\Package\Resources\Resource;
use myname\Package\Resources\ExtendedResource;

class ResourceTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testArtistIsResource() {

        $resource = '\\myname\\Package\\Resources\\Resource';
        $main = new MainClass('Artist');
        $artist = $main->find(1383508);

        $this->assertTrue($artist instanceof $resource);
    }

}
```

This test passes. I am running the same code outside of the test directory and displaying values in the browser to see what happens. I am running the package in laravel and just running the comparison code on the homepage. For example the output of the following code is printed directly in the browser

```
$main = new MainClass('Artist');
$artist = $main->find(1383508);

echo get_class($main); 
echo get_class($artist);
```

This shows that $main is a *myname\Package\MainClass* and $artist is a *myname\Package\Resources\ExtendedResource*. If I change the second echo statement above to this:

```
echo get_class($artist->get());
```

Then the result is that *stdClass* is echoed to the screen, which is correct. However in the test class $artist->get() returns an instance of *ResourceTest* and I don't understand why it is not another *stdClass*.

What am I missing?

My directory structure is as follows:

```
myname
|- Package
   |- composer.json
   |- src
      |- MainClass.php
      |- Resources
          |- Resource.php
          |- ExtendsResource.php
   |- tests
      |- Resources
         |- ResourceTest.php
```

Below is the content of the autoload part of composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "myname\\Package\\": "src/"
     }
}
```

I tried adding another namespace in there - "myname\Package\tests\": "tests/" - but that didn't seem to help.

The namespace for *MainClass.php* is *myname\Package*.

The namespace for *Resources.php* and *ExtendsResources.php* is *myname\Package\Resources*.

Here is the code for MainClass.php

```
<?php

namespace myname\Package;

class MainClass {

    private $resource;

    public function __construct($resource = null) {

        Container::setup();

        if ($resource) {
            $this->resource = Container::get($resource);
        }

        return $this->resource;
    }


    public function find($id) {

        if (isset ($this->resource)) {
            $this->resource->find($id);
            return $this->resource;
        }
        else { throw new \Exception('Resource is not set'); }

    }


    public function setResource($resource) {

        $this->resource = Container::get($resource);
        return $this->resource;
    }

}
```

Below is the code for myname\Package\Resources\Reource

```
<?php

namespace myname\Package\Resources;

use myname\Package\Contracts\ConfigInterface;
use myname\Package\Contracts\GrabberInterface;
use myname\Package\Contracts\ResourceInterface;
use myname\Package\Http\Grabber;
use myname\Package\Http\Poster;


abstract class Resource {

    protected $config           = null;     
    protected $url              = null;     
    protected $resource         = null;     
    protected $response         = null;     
    protected $grabber          = null;     
    protected $perPage          = null;     
    protected $page             = null;     
    protected $params           = null;     
    protected $token            = null;     
    protected $identifier       = null;     
    protected $update           = array();



    protected $appendTokenTo    = array(
        'myname\Package\Resources\Artist',
        'myname\Package\Resources\Listing',
        'myname\Package\Resources\Release',
        'myname\Package\Resources\Search'
    );


    public function __construct($config, $grabber) {

        if ($config instanceof ConfigInterface) {

            $this->config = $config;
        } else { throw new \Exception('The supplied $config is not an instance of ConfigInterface'); }


        if ($grabber instanceof GrabberInterface) {

            $this->grabber = $grabber;
        } else { throw new \Exception('The supplied $grabber is not an instance of GrabberInterface'); }

        $this->url         .= $this->config->getApiUrl() . $this->resource;
        $this->token        = $this->config->getApiToken();

        return $this;
    }



    public function addParam($param, $value) {

        $value= $this->formatParamValue($value);
        $this->params .= "&". "$param=$value";
        return $this;

    }


    protected function addToken(){

        $this->addParam('token', $this->token);
        //$this->params .= "&". "token=$this->token";
        return $this;
    }



    public function addUpdate($update, $value) {
        $this->update[$update] = $value;
        return $this;
    }



    protected function checkIfTokenIsRequired() {

        if (in_array(get_class($this), $this->appendTokenTo)) {
            $this->addToken();
        }

    }



    public function find($identifier) {

        if (empty ($this->identifier)) {
            $this->identifier = $identifier;
            $this->url .= "/$identifier";
        }
        return $this;

    }


    protected function formatParamValue($value) {
        $value = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $value);
        $value = str_replace(' ', '+', $value);
        return $value;
    }



    public function get() {

        return json_decode($this->getResponse());

    }


    protected function getResponse() {

        if (!isset($this->response)) {
            $this->checkIfTokenIsRequired();
            $this->_prepare();
        }

        return $this->response;

    }


    public function json() {

        return $this->getResponse();

    }



    public function page($pageNumber) {

        $this->page = $pageNumber;
        return $this;
    }



    public function perPage($resultsPerPage) {

        $this->perPage = $resultsPerPage;
        return $this;
    }


    protected function _prepare() {

        $params = 0;

        if (isset($this->page) OR isset($this->perPage) OR isset($this->params)){
            $this->url .= '?';
        }


        if (isset($this->params)) {

            $this->url .= "$this->params";
            $params++;
        }


        if (isset($this->perPage)) {

            if ($params > 0) {
                $this->url .= '&';
            }

            $this->url .= "per_page=$this->perPage";
            $params++;
        }

        if (isset($this->page)) {

            if ($params > 0) {
                $this->url .= '&';
            }

            $this->url .= "page=$this->page";
            $params++;
        }


        $this->grabber->setUrl($this->url);
        $this->response = $this->grabber->grab();
    }



    public function setGrabber($grabber) {

        if ($grabber instanceof GrabberInterface) {

            $this->grabber = $grabber;

        } else { throw new \Exception($grabber . " is not an instance of GrabberInterface"); }
    }



    public function setUrl($url) {
        $this->url = $url;
    }



    public function update() {

        //$this->update['token'] = $this->token;
        $this->grabber->setMethod('POST');
        $this->grabber->setUpdates(json_encode($this->update));
        $this->_prepare();
        return $this;

    }


}
```

Below is the code for the ExtendedResource

```
<?php

namespace myname\Package\Resources;


class ExtendedResource extends Resource {

    protected $resource = 'artists';

    /**
     * Returns the releases associated with an artist
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function releases() {

        $this->url .= '/releases';
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of `MainClass`?

Comment: Hi @StoryTeller code added

Comment: Sorry, looking at the question again, `myname\Package\Resources\ExtendedResource` would be helpful, too

Comment: Thanks, @Storyteller I have added that now

Comment: Well now I see `get()` returns `$this->response` which is generated by an object implementing `GrabberInterface`... I suggest you look in your code for the reason, starting with the `grab()` method. PHPUnit shouldn't affect the code it is trying to test, everything else would be unreasonable.